# Error: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I get this error:

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:
>
> DisplayNameFor<IEnumerable<Category>,string>(HtmlHelper<IEnumerable<Category>>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<IEnumerable,string>>)
>
> and
>
> DisplayNameFor<Category,string>(HtmlHelper<IEnumerable>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<Category,string>>)

My model is

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

My Context Model is

```
public class CategoryContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Category> category { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller is :

```
public ActionResult GetCategory()
{
    using (CategoryContext cc = new CategoryContext())
    {
        var cat = cc.category.ToList();
        return View();
    }
}
```

My View is :

```
@model IEnumerable<CRUD_Manav_EF.Models.Category>

<h1>Get Category</h1>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CategoryName)</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => item.CategoryName) // I get error here
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Update", new { id = item.CategoryId })
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.CategoryId })
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.CategoryId })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: It makes no sense to repeat the text "CategoryName" in each row especially when you already have that text in the header. I assume you mean `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryName)` (not `DisplayNameFor()`) which will output the value of the property, not its name

Comment: @StephenMuecke And that's why he is getting error because he is using @Html.DisplayNameFor() instead of @Html.DisplayFor()

Comment: @Rajput, Yes I know :)

Comment: Yes I am learing form you :) @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 0):

This error is displaying because you have used
 `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CategoryName)` in table foreach loop and call would ambiguous between those method mentioned above. Since there is no benefit of using Display name again and again while iterating. if you will see the whole description of `@Html.DisplayNameFor()` you will get that the first parameter accept only model(lambda expression) and not IEnumerable of model. This is also shown in your compiler error.

see in example screenshot (this is dummy project)

[image]

Use `@html.DisplayFor(..)` instead in your foreach loop.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Update", new { id = item.CategoryId })
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.CategoryId })
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.CategoryId })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

This htmlhelper method will take IEnumerable of your model. And your issue will be resolved(you can check it yourself).

Comment: thanks buddy its solved , i need some help in Authentication & Authorization with mvc (custom)

Comment: Please mark this answer as Accepted answer and upvote it so that it can be useful for other user Thanks @ManavPandya